# Example usage of "laic"

Tags: word-usage

I failed to find example usage of *laic* after a few minutes of search. I think it should be used this way:

> I am laic at physics.

Is this correct? Should I use *layman* instead?

Comment: Neat word! I had never heard of "laic" before. It's a synonym for "layman," and you should be able to use the words interchangeably. You just need to add the article "a", i.e. "I am a layman at physics" or "I am a laic at physics." Yes, a quick search of Google Books confirms this usage, as in the following quote from a book on this history of baptism: "Those whom a laic baptized are to be rebaptized... therefore an Arian priest is not a laic."

Comment: You can’t have searched very thoroughly. The [first online dictionary I tried](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/laic) has several usage examples of the word.

Comment: If you want people to understand you, use 'lay' (adj) or 'layman/layperson' (noun) instead. 'Laic' must be a very rare word (it sounds like an attempt to translate French to English, without knowing lay or layman).

Comment: I daren't even begin to analyse [these Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=layman+at%2Claic%2Clayman+when+it+comes+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clayman%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clayman%20when%20it%20comes%20to%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Mitch Actually Hungarian. :-)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually it is better to use a recent interval: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=layman+at%2Claic%2Clayman+when+it+comes+to&year_start=2000&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clayman%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clayman%20when%20it%20comes%20to%3B%2Cc0 but it has the same result, according to this laic is more prevalent than layman.

Comment: Your ngram choice is misleading. Just [compare layman and laic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=layman%2C+laic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3). Also, when you look at the examples for 'laic', [most of its entries are for the acronym LAIC](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22laic%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1953,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=ssl). But some examples there do show a non-problematic usage of 'laic' in contrast to 'cleric'. But I'd say that almost anywhere in English like in the context of you original question, you should avoid 'laic'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(a+layman)%2B(a+laywoman)%2B(a+layperson)%2Ca+lay+_NOUN_%2Ca+laic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28a%20layman%29%20%2B%20%28a%20laywoman%29%20%2B%20%28a%20layperson%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20lay%20_NOUN_%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20laic%3B%2Cc0) at the bottom. *Laic* is a very rare word, and it is likely that many of your readers or hearers will not recognize it. It is used almost exclusively in religious contexts, contrasting with *cleric* or *priest*.

The more usual adjective is *lay*, but this too is used more in the religious sphere—lay readers, lay counselors and the like—than outside it. Educated audiences will have no problem with a figurative use: "I have only a lay understanding of physics."

The noun *layman*, however, should be familiar to most people, and it is widely used outside religious discourse in the figurative sense of "non-expert"—someone who has not mastered the inner mysteries of a particular discipline or craft.

Note, however, that the various mutations of *lay* are used of persons who do not pursue mastery in the discipline under consideration. If you are a student of physics who has not yet progressed very far you would do better to describe yourself as a *novice*—another term of religious art which is widely used in a figurative sense.

[image: laic,lay,layman]

Comment: Thanks! I never studied physics, that's why I wrote that sentence. In Hungarian "laikus" is an everyday word (it means the same as layman).

Comment: Hungary must be the laikus district.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you laica me like I laica you ...

Comment: Either you're a photographer or a reincarnation of Chico.